# if parent check box is checked then check child check box in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

i have 2 check boxis:

```
         @foreach ($orders as order)

<span>Map view</span><br><input type="checkbox" class="parent" value="{{ $order->id }}" />

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{ $order->customers->location_url }}" data-rowid="{{ $order->id }}" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox1[]" value="{{ $order->customers->user->name }}" data-rowid="{{ $order->id }}" class="child" />

        @endforeach
```

**i want if parent is checked child of both data-rowid should be checked**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('input.parent').on('change', function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.child[data-rowid |="'+id+'"]').attr('checked', true);
    }else{
        $('.child[data-rowid |="'+id+'"]').attr('checked', false);
    }
})
```

Comment: worked but one issue in @foreach loop it is checking all rows but i want to check only data-rowid(selected row)

Comment: where is foreach you didnt show it if you want full answer post your full code

Comment: foreach loop added i am to pass order->id as value to parent and then compare to row-id  with child id and then chek or unchek

Comment: using foreach loop i am getting all record from db with ids yor code check/unchek all record but i want selected one only so logic is i need to get id of parent check box value={{ "$order->id }}" then checked or unchecked to same child data-rowid = "{{ $order->id }}"

Comment: great bro you are genious

Comment: @HamzaQureshi happy coding